# Identifying lines in $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ and $M$ be two lines in $\mathbb P^2$.  Does there exist a map $f : \mathbb P^2 \to X$ that "identifies" $L$ and $M$, in the sense that $f\vert \mathbb P^2 \setminus (L \cup M)$ is an isomorphism, and $f(L) = f(M)$, with $f\vert_L$ and $f\vert_M$ isomorphisms as well?

Comment: Fix a projectivity $\phi:\Bbb P^2\rightarrow\Bbb P^2$ that sends $L$ onto $M$ and then take the quotient $X=\Bbb P^2/\sim_\phi$ where a point $P\in L$ is identified to $f(P)\in M$. Then let $f$ be the quotient map.

Comment: What is the quotient of a variety by a map?  Such a thing doesn't make sense, unless $\phi$ has finite order.  But even then you fail to satisfy $f\vert_{\mathbb P^2 \setminus L \cup M}$ being an isomorphism, because you identify other pairs of lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of construction is usually called "pinching" or "glueing along closed subschemes".

I'm really not an expert on these things, but as far as I know, the definitive treatment is the article [Conducteur, Descente, et Pincement](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~daniel.ferrand/Conducteur.pdf) by Daniel Ferrand.

If I understand correctly, your question is answered by Théorème 5.4 in that article: paraphrasing, this says

> If $X$ is a scheme, $Y'$ a closed subscheme of $X$ and $\phi: Y' \rightarrow Y$ a finite morphism, we can "pinch" $X$ along $\phi$, changing $Y'$ into $Y$ and leaving the rest of $X$ unchanged.

Applying this with $X=\mathbf P^2$, $Y'=L \cup M$, $Y=\mathbf P^1$, and $Y' \rightarrow Y$ the obvious finite map should give what you want.